# Grails Spring Batch plugin not finding jobs

Tags: spring, grails, groovy, jvm, spring-batch

I'm working on a project with Grails 3.3.7 and I'm trying to get the Spring Batch to work using the grails-spring-batch. Just like in the documentation example, I created a MySimpleJobBatchConfig.groovy file in the grails-app/batch directory with the following content :

```
import myapp.PrintMessageTasklet;

beans {
    xmlns batch:"http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"

    batch.job(id: 'mySimpleJob') {
        batch.step(id: 'logStart') {
            batch.tasklet(ref: 'printMessage')
        }
    }

    printMessage(PrintMessageTasklet) { bean ->
        bean.autowire = "byName"
    }
}
```

PrintMessageTasklet is defined as such in `src/main/groovy/myapp/PrintMessageTasklet.groovy` :

```
package myapp

import org.springframework.batch.core.StepContribution
import org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.ChunkContext
import org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.Tasklet
import org.springframework.batch.repeat.RepeatStatus

class PrintMessageTasklet implements Tasklet {
    RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution stepContribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) {
        println "Test"
        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED
    }
}
```

And here's the service that's trying to launch the job in `grails-app/services/myapp/SimpleJobService` :

```
package myapp

import grails.gorm.transactions.Transactional
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParameters
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing

@Transactional
class SimpleJobService {

    def jobLauncher;
    def mySimpleJob;

    def launchSimpleJob() {
        jobLauncher.run(mySimpleJob, new JobParameters())
    }
}
```

However, when I run `launchSimpleJob`, I get the following exception telling me that `mySimpleJob` is null, despite me having defined it in the MySimpleJobBatchConfig.groovy file.

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsControllerClass$ReflectionInvoker.invoke(DefaultGrailsControllerClass.java:211)
    at org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsControllerClass.invoke(DefaultGrailsControllerClass.java:188)
    at org.grails.web.mapping.mvc.UrlMappingsInfoHandlerAdapter.handle(UrlMappingsInfoHandlerAdapter.groovy:90)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55)
    at org.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:77)
    at org.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:67)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The Job must not be null.
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:134)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:94)
    at myapp.SimpleJobService.$tt__launchSimpleJob(SimpleJobService.groovy:14)
    at grails.gorm.transactions.GrailsTransactionTemplate$2.doInTransaction(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:94)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133)
    at grails.gorm.transactions.GrailsTransactionTemplate.execute(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:91)
    at myapp.SimpleJobController.launch(SimpleJobController.groovy:9)
    ... 14 common frames omitted
```

If I try to start my job using `springBatchService.launch('mySimpleJob')` instead, the message in the returned map also tells me that it couldn't find the job named "mySimpleJob".

Since I'm quite new to Groovy and Spring Batch and I followed carefully the documentation of this plugin I can't find what's wrong. Does anyone knows how to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it, the plugin documentation was outdated, turns out my BatchConfing needed to be in the `src/main/resources/batch` folder instead of the `grails-app/batch` folder.

Also had to change `@Transactional` to `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED)` in my service.

Comment: "Also had to change @Transactional to @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED) in my service." - That is indeed surprising. If you can describe at https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues the circumstances under which that is required we would be happy to investigate.  Thank you for the feedback.